# Spring Oauth2 introspect a token only without client_id and client_secret

Tags: java, spring-boot, oauth-2.0

The implementation was to customize the endpoint to check the token in Oauth2 authorizarion server in spring which /oauth2/introspect Sample: `http://localhost:8080/oauth2/introspect?token=tokenValueHere&client_id=client&client_secret=secret` but the requirement is to check the token only without client_id and client_secret.

Have try to customize it, the method `getAuthenticationProvider`
But when i try without client_id and client_secret it will  401 Unauthorized and the print `Going to this method` is not showing which mean the method is not being excuted, its being block.

Would like to ask where to modified  `/oauth2/introspect` to required without client_id and client_secret?

```
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration.applyDefaultSecurity(http);
        http.getConfigurer(OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigurer.class)
                .tokenIntrospectionEndpoint(a -> a.authenticationProvider(getAuthenticationProvider()));
        

        http.csrf().disable();
        

        return http.build();
    }

    private AuthenticationProvider getAuthenticationProvider() {
    System.out.println("Going to this method");
        return new AuthenticationProvider() {
            @Override
            public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
            
                if (authentication.getPrincipal() == null || authentication.getCredentials() == null) {
                    return authentication;
                }
                throw new BadCredentialsException("Invalid credentials");
            }
            @Override
            public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
                return OAuth2TokenIntrospectionAuthenticationToken.class.isAssignableFrom(authentication);
            }
        };
```

```
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-authorization-server</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
```